# Amazon S3 - Directly upload to S3IA: Possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-serverless, amazon-glacier

We are to be migrating archived files to AWS. Since the files will be infrequently accessed but need to be accessed right away, we thought that Amazon S3 Infrequent Access would be the best storage class used for this.

Problem is, can you directly upload files to S3IA without passing S3 Standard? thats the first question. In our case, lets say we have a program in NodeJS or Python that we want to directly upload files to S3IA.

If the answer to the first question is yes, what if we need the uploaded files encrypted (using KMS). Is this also possible to do in S3IA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can you directly upload files to S3IA without passing S3 Standard?

Yes, you can. You can set `StorageClass` in [put_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) to `STANDARD_IA`.

For encryption you can use `ServerSideEncryption` parameter.

Comment: But S3IA is different from intelligent tiering right?

Comment: @XmusJacksonFlaxonWaxon So use `STANDARD_IA`. I updated the answer.

Comment: ok. follow up question. can you also do file integrity checks in IA? something like this -> https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/data-integrity-s3/

Comment: @XmusJacksonFlaxonWaxon I would suggest new question for the integrity check.